# Не появляется иконка в трее...

Tags: winforms, c++

Добрый день.

Хочу поместить иконку моей программы в трей, ничего не выходит... Вернее с однооконным приложением всё получается, а когда переношу уже на многооконное, то вроде как всё работает, только нет иконки в трее( Код моего приложения большой для его размещения тут... В чем может крыться причина?

```
    Form1.h
    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
        {

        private: System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripMenuItem^  авторыToolStripMenuItem;
        private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label3;
        private: System::Windows::Forms::RichTextBox^  richTextBox3;
                 //private: System::Windows::Forms::NotifyIcon^  notifyIcon1;
        private: System::Windows::Forms::NotifyIcon^  fIcon1;

    ...
В функции инициализации:
this->fIcon1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::NotifyIcon(this->components));
.... 
            // fIcon1
            // 
            this->fIcon1->Icon = (cli::safe_cast<System::Drawing::Icon^  >(resources->GetObject(L"fIcon1.Icon")));
            this->fIcon1->Text = L"notifyIcon1";
            this->fIcon1->Visible = true;
            this->fIcon1->MouseDoubleClick += gcnew System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventHandler(this, &Form1::fIcon1_MouseDoubleClick);

....
```

Comment: MDI-приложение состоит из трех типов окон: фрейм, клиент и дочернее. Вложены они именно в таком порядке. Следовательно уведомления от трея нужно перехватывать **именно во фрейм-окне**. Возможно проблема в этом.

Comment: Я новичек.. Посмотрел в сети, что-то ничего не нашел полезного.. Как можно определить тип окона?

Comment: В winforms не подскажу, я специализируюсь на WinAPI, но вот возможно поможет:
1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049479/simple-mdi-parent-and-mdichild-winforms
2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941362/winforms-mdi-child-forms
3. http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/154998/Get-Active-MDI-Child-form-at-winform-app

Вобщем-то гугл все это вещает по ключам `winforms` и `mdichild`, т.к. mdichild-уже довольно устоявшийся термин.

Comment: К успеху не пришел( Может кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой? Как выпутались?